# Buscar entre datas em 2 colunas da mesma tabela

Tags: mysql

Colegas.

Tenho uma tabela que traz o início e o fim de um evento.

```
InicioEvento = 2016-06-01 07:00:00 
FimEvento = 2016-12-31 00:00:00
```

Sei que se eu usar o BETWEEN, consigo fazer  busca entre datas, mas como eu faria entre datas com duas colunas? Tentei dessa forma, mas naõ sei se está correto:

```
select * from eventos where  (inicio_eventos BETWEEN '2016-02-22 00:00:00' and '2016-12-31 00:00:00') and  (fim_eventos BETWEEN '2016-02-22 00:00:00' and '2016-12-31 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deveria escolher uma das colunas a serem comparadas, ou se quiser incluir as duas, poderia utilizar "AND" na comparação.

```
Where <campo_sql_1> Between InicioEvento AND FimEvento
  And <campo_sql_2> Between InicioEvento AND FimEvento
```